# Condition format the cell if the cell above it is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this is my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WG7uxV9g7l67-vYA00Avn8cN4BIBQSjDMoe_85XG1Fg/edit?usp=sharing)

I'd like to highlight the cell if the cell above it is not empty

I use this formula in conditional formatting `=NOT(ISBLANK(A1))` but it [doesn't work as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F3ZI.png)

I've also tried this formula `=NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)))` and it doesn't work as well

The ultimate result I'm trying to get is only A23 is highlighted if A22 is not empty, then if A23 is not empty, A24 will get highlighted and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying conditional formatting to `A1:A` you can use:

`=NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)))`

In your example you apply it to `A5:A1004`, so a simpler solution could be used:

`=A4 <> ""`

[image]

To only highlight the empty cell right after the last non-empty one use the rule:

`=AND(A5 = "", A4 <> "")`

[image]

Comment: Hi kishkin, thank you for the suggestion but this outcome is not what I looking for. I want only A23 to get highlighted not all the cells above A23. Is there other suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula if you select A1:A range:**

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET(A1,-1,0))),ISBLANK(A1))
```

**But based on your sample sheet you selected A5:A1004, Use this formula instead:**

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET(A5,-1,0))),ISBLANK(A5)
```

**Rationale:**

- Checking the previous row is not enough to achieve your goal. You need to check if previous row is not empty and the current row is empty before highlighting the current row.

**Output:**

[image]